# Not able to load spartacus storefront after Upgrading spartacus from 3.0.0 to 3.3.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

After upgrading spartacus version from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0 getting below error while loading storefront. No error on Yarn build or server startup but only when trying to open storefront
[errors visible in developers tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7QEM.png)

Comment: The issue is already addressed in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12632. You can find a quick workaround fix in the comment: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12632#issuecomment-852198709

Answer (score 0):

Replace static property `ModalService.rootComponent` with a getter that is evaluated lazy (not during the service instantiation), but only when #modal method is called.

```
protected get rootComponent() {
    return this.applicationRef?.components?.[0]?.location?.nativeElement;
 }
```

See https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12632#issuecomment-852198709